# AXIOM marshalling: how to Reduce memory consumption for OMNamespaceImpl?

Tags: java, spring-ws

I have a large XML result containing thousand xml nodes.

When JAXB / AXIOM process data BEAN to construct SOAP response, i got a memory peak (+500Mb). When i analyzed JVM memory dump with eclipse MAT, i noticed 
a lot of AXIOM OMNamespaceImpl instances.

When i look at AXIOM StAXSOAPModelBuilder, i see interesting setter (namespaceURIInterning) allowing interning String in order to reduce memory consumption.

Any suggestions to customize JAXB / AXIOM perfom in Jaxb2Marshaller.marshal() ?

regards,
JF.Desmarais

axiom 1.2.14
spring-ws 2.1.4
JDK 1.7

Spring-ws code extract to build current SOAP Response :

```
public final void invoke(MessageContext messageContext) throws Exception {
        WebServiceMessage request = messageContext.getRequest();
        Object requestObject = unmarshalRequest(request);
        if (onUnmarshalRequest(messageContext, requestObject)) {
            Object responseObject = invokeInternal(requestObject);
            if (responseObject != null) {
                WebServiceMessage response = messageContext.getResponse();
                marshalResponse(responseObject, response);
                onMarshalResponse(messageContext, requestObject, responseObject);
            }
        }
    }   
 public WebServiceMessage getResponse() {
        if (response == null) {
            response = messageFactory.createWebServiceMessage();
        }
        return response;
    }

 public AxiomSoapMessage createWebServiceMessage() {
        return new AxiomSoapMessage(soapFactory, payloadCaching, langAttributeOnSoap11FaultString);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the deprecated `AbstractMarshallingPayloadEndpoint` class. Switching to annotation based endpoints will enable some optimizations (support for `StreamingWebServiceMessage`) that should avoid the problem you describe.